# An exclamation for showing resentment when departing?

Tags: exclamations

There are a couple of different exclamations for when you depart from someone, such as *bye*, *bye-bye*, *good-bye*, *see you*, etc. Is there any departing exclamation for when you want to show that you are resented from/hate the one you are departing from?

Obviously, *goodbye* is not good because it has *good* in it; similarly, *see you* means the contrary of what I am looking for. *Bye* and *bye-bye* are kinda neutral.

I also don't want such outspoken offence such as *go fuck yourself*!

Funny, I once used *so long* for that purpose because I thought it had the connotation of *it is enough* or *I spent too much time with you*.

So is there any such exclamation to show bitterness, hatred, or resentment?

Comment: Yes  you say goodbye with a tone that indicates clearly your feelings. Or you add a word such as bitch or dickhead.

Comment: @Clare The question is edited.

Comment: Bye-bye is not neutral. It is informal and familiar, usually indicating some type  however slight  of emotional connection between the conversants.

Comment: Well, hatred and resentment are often expressed verbally through profanity. But if you don't want to do that you say goodbye with ice in your eyes and malice in your voice.

Answer (score 4):

Does "good riddance" come close to what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

"*See you never.*"

"*See you next Tuesday!*"  A veiled anatomical insult, said brightly by a departing female to a disagreeable female.  The first two words represent a phonetic spelling out of the insult, which is completed by the first letters of the last two words.

"*Don't let the door hit you on the way out!*"

Comment: Lol https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=See+You+Next+Tuesday  apparently not what the OP wants, but clever.

Comment: It's like saying *(i)f you see Kay* when I was in sixth grade.